# How to only return subset of larger query in GraphQL without returning the whole thing?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

I am new to GraphQL and trying to understand how to only return a subsection of the resulting query. For example, here is my cypher query in Neo4j:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[HAS_FRIEND]-(f:User)
WHERE u.name = "Joe"
RETURN f.name
```

Notice how the above query only returns the friend names.

### GraphQL

Here's a sample of GraphQL version of the above cypher query.

##### Input

```
{
    "where": {
        "name": "Joe"
    }
}
```

##### Query

```
query Query($where: NameWhere) {
  names(where: $where) {
    name
    friends {
        name
    }
  }
}
```

### Expected Output

Obviously, I expect output to include friends name array and the name of the user having the friend. But, what if I only want the friends array like the cypher query gives me?

While this is a simple example, I am using a graph database that has a series of connections and my nesting is looking pretty deep, but I only really need a subquery from the result. A great example is with localization - I don't need the country and language (locale), etc. in every query; I only want the subquery result (e.g. the spelling in UK/ENG is `colour` and in US/ENG is `color`).

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j offers a Javascript GraphQL library that is able to handle your use case (and many more)!

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/introduction/) for information on how to get started. See even the example queries, where [this one](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/queries/#_query_for_user_with_name_jane_smith_and_their_posts) is fairly close to what you are looking for.

Anyhow, the GraphQL query provided above, using the `@neo4j/graphql` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neo4j/graphql), could look like so:

```
query Query {
  users (where: { name: "Joe" }) {
     friends {
        name
     }
  }
}
```

(Note that the where parameter ("Joe") is provided in-line in this case)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, but this still returns fully nested structure of `users, friends, name`. Is there a way to perform a sort of subquery that doesn't return full structure when it's unnecessary? Essentially, I want to have condition of `name = Joe` but only return the section of `friends, name` and not the outer `users` object unnecessarily. The logic may contain a lot of sub-objects and conditions, but essentially, we only want the very small subset of objects.

Comment: The GraphQL version of the cypher code returns more objects and a larger structure than necessary. My question is less about using conditions and more about how to reduce data transfer with increased query complexity.

Comment: Is my option here using the `@cypher` schema directive to bind a field to a cypher query? Something like `@cypher: statement: """MATCH (u:User)-[HAS_FRIEND]-(f:User)
WHERE u.name = "Joe"
RETURN {name: f.name}"""`

Comment: Yes @ctwheels, the `@cypher` directive is your best choice for this use case! It gives you the flexibility you need. Just in case, see the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/type-definitions/cypher/).